# 404 ошибка при перенаправлении Ajax-запроса

Tags: javascript, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Делаю сайт, в котором локализация работает через параметр:

```
http://sitename.com/team.php?lang=ru
```

Для того, что бы привести *URL* к понятному виду, использую следующий `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)$ $2?lang=$1
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

Он переводит ссылки в формат:

```
http://sitename.com/ru/team
```

Но возникла проблема: если с одной из страниц я *Ajax-ом* пытаюсь обратиться к другому скрипту, то сервер возвращает 404 ошибку (файл не найден).

Адрес *ajax-запроса* выглядит следующим образом:

```
url: '../core/backend/backapi.php'
```

Структура папок у меня организована подобным образом:

[image: Структура папок у меня организована подобным образом]

*JS-файлы* находятся в папке *js*. Если я оттуда попытаюсь отправить *Ajax-запрос* к файлу `backapi.php`, то получу ошибку. При удалении строки

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)$ $2?lang=$1
```

Запрос отправляется нормально, но пропадает понятный человеку *URL*.

Comment: А URL `../core/backend/backapi.php` ведь и не должен модифицироваться этим правилом?

Comment: Нет, не должен. Но фактически, он отправляется с клиента, поэтому насколько я понимаю, сервер как-то воздействует правилом и на него тоже.

Answer (score 1):

Проверил Ваш htaccess и правила конечно работает на эту ссылку тоже

сейчас Вас htaccess создает ссылку так

```
http://site.com/core/backend/backapi.php => http://site.com/backapi.php?lang=core/backend
```

Из этого не работает ваш Ajax запрос

```
debugging info
1       RewriteEngine on    
2       RewriteBase /   

3       RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)$ $2?lang=$1  
            Это правило совпадает и дает результат http://site.com/backapi.php?lang=core/backend

4       RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
            Переменная не поддерживается : %{REQUEST_FILENAME}

5       RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 
            Переменная не поддерживается: %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php

6       RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php   
            Правило не сработало, один из ситуаций не совпадает
```

проверил на сайте http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/ попробуйте

Answer (score 1):

вероятно, вот эта строка:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)$ $2?lang=$1
```

должна звучать несколько иначе. например, так (для двух языковых версий):

```
RewriteRule ^(ru|en)/(.*)$ $2?lang=$1
```